# How to find the "lowest" element from array<struct>?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a dataframe with following schema -

```
|-- ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- VALUES: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- _v1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _v2: string (nullable = true)
```

VALUES are like -

```
[["1","a"],["2","b"],["3","c"],["4","d"]]
[["4","g"]]
[["3","e"],["4","f"]]
```

I want to take the VALUES with the lowest integer i.e.
The result df should look like - (which will be StructType now, not Array[Struct])

```
["1","a"]
["4","g"]
["3","e"]
```

Can someone please guide me how can I approach this problem by creating a udf ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a UDF for that. Just use `sort_array` and pick the first element.

```
df.show
+--------------------+
|            data_arr|
+--------------------+
|[[4,a], [2,b], [1...|
|             [[1,a]]|
|      [[3,b], [1,v]]|
+--------------------+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- data_arr: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = false)


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sort_array

df.withColumn("first_asc", sort_array($"data_arr")(0)).show
+--------------------+---------+
|            data_arr|first_asc|
+--------------------+---------+
|[[4,a], [2,b], [1...|    [1,c]|
|             [[1,a]]|    [1,a]|
|      [[3,b], [1,v]]|    [1,v]|
+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same dataframe as in the example:

```
val findSmallest = udf((rows: Seq[Row]) => {
    rows.map(row => (row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[String](1))).sorted.head
})

df.withColumn("SMALLEST", findSmallest($"VALUES"))
```

Will give a result like this:

```
+---+--------------------+--------+
| ID|              VALUES|SMALLEST|
+---+--------------------+--------+
|  1|[[1,a], [2,b], [3...|   [1,2]|
|  2|             [[4,e]]|   [4,g]|
|  3|      [[3,g], [4,f]]|   [3,g]|
+---+--------------------+--------+
```

If you only want the final values use `select("SMALLEST)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But there is slight difference what I want to achieve and what you suggested. I didn't explained it properly. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Ishan I'd say that change is large enough to warrant a new question. Especially since this one has two answers already answering the old one.

Comment: Okay, I will post a new question for this.